# Как разным потокам передавать разные параметры?

Tags: c#, многопоточность

есть программа эмулирующая работу в браузере, для того чтобы зайти на сайт, нужно ввести логин и пароль. Пароль на всех аккаунтах одинаковый, а логин разный. Я пытаюсь запустить 5 одинаковых потоков, но при этом каждый раз передавать в функцию разный параметр логина. Логин имеет форму "bbb001", "bbb002" и т.д. К сожалению, у меня не получается, надеюсь на вашу помощь.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Auto auto = new Auto("");
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                Thread LogIn = new Thread(new ThreadStart(auto.GoToURL));
                LogIn.Start();
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

```
public class Auto
    {
        private string bbb;

        public Auto(string _bbb)
        {
            List<string> log = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
            {
                log.Add("bbb" + string.Format("{0:000.#}", i));
            }
            foreach (var k in log)
            {
                this.bbb = _bbb+k;
            }

        }
        public void GoToURL()
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://");

            IWebElement login = driver.FindElement(By.Id("login"));

            login.SendKeys(bbb);
            IWebElement password = driver.FindElement(By.Id("password"));
            password.SendKeys("123456");
            IWebElement come = driver.FindElement(By.Id("submit"));
            come.Click();
            driver.Quit();
        }
```

я тут пытался передать через экземпляр класса, но само собой таким способом ничего не будет работать.
как лучше решить этот вопрос я не знаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример, который должен помочь:

TestClass.cs:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public TestClass(int id, string value)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Value = value;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Id: {Id}, Value: {Value}.";
    }
}
```

Запуск в нескольких потоках:

```
Enumerable.Range(1, 5).ToList().ForEach(i => {                      // цикл из 5ти элементов
    new Thread(func => {                                            // создаю новый поток с функцией
        TestClass cl = new TestClass(i, (i * 10).ToString());       // в потоке создаю экземпляр класса с итеративной переменной
        Console.WriteLine(cl.ToString());                           // делаю действия с ней (вывожу)
    }).Start();                                                     // запускаю поток
});
```

Ну и результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: немного непонятно как это работает. понимаю что если прочитать туториалы всё станет яснее, но я не смог найти что-то толкового. в первой строке вы создаете массив из 5 элементов, преобразуете в список и сразу же запускаете с неявным определением i в цикле новый поток?

Comment: @ДмитрийФадин в принципе можно и так сказать, но лучше посмотря на то что я написал, посмотрите как оно работает, и почитайте...так писать не совсем хорошо. Я написал чисто для примера

Comment: Да, я понимаю что так не очень хорошо писать,но я уже написал нужную функцию, с помощью вашего примера,а другого способа я не нашел, несколько дней пытался сам что-то придумать, из всех моих попыток ничего толкового не вышло.Спасибо